# Interaction of Trypsin or Chymotrypsin with alcohol

Tags: alcohol, drug-interactions, enzyme, hemorrhage, blood-shot-eyes

Does Trypsin + Chymotrypsin (100000 AU) tablet interact with alcohol? I have been prescribed this for a subconjuctival hemorrhage. Online searches led me nowhere on this.

Comment: @Lucky Could you help us out?